# detect key-sequence in vb.net application and set focus to specific field

Tags: vb.net, keypress

I have a barcode scanner. Each time this barcode scanner scanns something it first types @@1 and then the code it has read. I would like my app to set focus to a specific textbox whenever it detects the sequence @@1 regardless of what is selected/active when i am scanning. (for instance the focus could be on the form itself, or on an image, or in a table or whatever..)
The only way I have found is to use a global keyhook using getasynckeystate but its not good practice since most antivirus programs see it as a keylogger. I also do not need them to be detected when the program is not in focus.. only when in focus. Is there a proper way to detect all the Keys pressed while the application is active, that does not upset the antivirus programs?

Comment: Depends how widely you want to apply this, which you haven't made clear. For instance, the keypreview event will do what you want within one form.

Comment: thanks, its all within a single form. will the keypreview work regardless what is selected/active?